# Time stamp using nosetests

Tags: python, timestamp, nosetests

I am running bunch of tests in a server over and over again and i want something that would record at what time the tests executed so that I can lookup which tests ran at what time.
Any suggestions how can i accomplish this?

Comment: I think some CI tools like travis, jenkins would help.

Comment: Can you pplease elaborate Yu Liang

Answer (score 0):

## Timestamped Test Report

If you just want a timestamp in a test report you can create a `bash` wrapper around your `nosetest` call that adds a timestamp to the beginning of the report.

**test.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# test
nosetests tests -v -d --with-coverage --cover-package=project --cover-tests --cover-erase --cover-inclusive --cover-branches &> test.txt.temp

# test report
echo '' > test_report.txt
echo 'Project Testing Report' >> test_report.txt
echo `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"` >> test_report.txt
echo '=========================================' >> test_report.txt
echo '' >> test_report.txt
cat test.txt.temp >> test_report.txt

rm .coverage
rm test.txt.temp

echo 'project tested'
```

**test_report.txt:**

```
Project Testing Report
2015-05-12 19:04:17 -0000
=========================================

test that this test passes ... ok
test that this test fails ... ok
...
```